# Induction question: $P(n): 2 + 4 + ... + 2n = (n + 2)(n - 1)$ for any integer $n \ge 2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have to find an error in an induction exercise and I believe the error is in the basic step.

Here is what I have,

$P(n): 2 + 4 + ... + 2n = (n + 2)(n - 1)$ for any integer $n \ge 2$.

My steps:

$P(2): 2n = (n + 2)(n - 1) \implies 2(2) = (2 + 2)(2 - 1) \implies 4 = 4,$ which is true

$P(3): 2n = (n + 2)(n - 1) \implies 2(3) = (3 + 2)(3 - 1) \implies 6 = 10$, which is false. This is why I believe the basic step has an error. Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: For $P(2)$, the sum is $2+4$.

Comment: Think of $P$ as follows: $P(n)=(2*1)+(2*2)+(2*3)+...+(2*n)$. So, for example, $P(4)=(2*1)+(2*2)+(2*3)+(2*4)=2+4+6+8=20$

Comment: Hi, this is good to know. I actually would have said that P(4) = 2n = 2(4) = 8 and not 20. I'll have to go and review this section again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are trying to prove an incorrect equation. Note that $$2 + 4 + \cdots + 2n = 2(1 + 2 + \cdots + n) = 2 \cdot \left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right) = n(n+1)$$

So $P(n)$ should be $$P(n):\quad2 + 4 +\cdots + n = n(n+1)$$

Then, you need only one base case: $P(2): \quad 2 + 4 = (2)(2 + 1) = 6$.

Now, the inductive hypothesis we want to assume: Assume $P(k): 2 + 4 \cdots + 2k = k(k+1)$

The task then is to show that, given the base case and the inductive hypothesis, it follows that $$P(k+1): 2 + 4 + \cdots + 2k + 2(k+1) = (k+1)(k+2)$$ To do this, start from the left-hand side of $P(k+1)$ and use the inductive hypothesis to show that the right-hand side follows.

Comment: Hi, I actually don't need to show an induction hypothesis or (k + 1). I have a complete exercise which includes the entire proof. I only need to show the error, which I believe is in the basic step.

Comment: Note that the left hand side of the base case is $ 2 + 4 = ...$ and not $2(n)$. I.e. it is $2(1) + 2(2) = \cdots$. Likewise, $P(3)$ should begin $2(1) + 2(2) + 2(3) = \cdots$. The other error is that the induction hypothesis, as stated in your post, is *not true*. That is, $P(n): 2 + 4 + \cdots + 2n \neq (n +2)(n - 1)$

Comment: Hi, I thought that the error was there but I was not sure how to prove it. I am going to review that section of the book again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, Tony!

Comment: @amWhy: More nice feedback! +1